# How to create a powerlaw distribution scale free network with given exponent gamma

Tags: python, graph

I've create a configuration sequence with the method on this site 

`https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55342/how-to-generate-a-degree-sequence-of-a-degree-distribution`

I got a degree sequence with 1000 nodes and a minimum degree 2. Now how can I generate a network whose degree distribution is exactly what the sequence shows?

Comment: What I need is a connected undirected graph by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the degree sequence given, you probably should use the algorithm by Havel and Hakimi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm

It works by iteratively connecting vertices until the degree sequence is either realized, or it has a proof that the given degree sequence cannot be realized (yes, that's a possibility).

Note that there are also algorithms that directly generate a graph with power-law distribution, without the indirection of creating a degree sequence first, for example "Forest Fire" generators or "Barabasi-Albert preferential attachment" generators.

If you are just looking to quickly generate such a graph and you know a bit of Python, the NetworKit library contains all of the mentioned generators (and much more): https://networkit.iti.kit.edu/